Can't confirmEmail VUEX
When I verified my e-mail already, the checkboxes in the local store don't change.
**** VUEX****
 async confirmEmail({ commit }) {
    try {
      const user = auth.currentUser;
      if (user) {
        await user.reload(); 

        if (user.emailVerified) {
     
          commit('SET_IS_USER_REGISTERED', true);
          commit('setShowNotification', false);
          localStorage.setItem('isUserRegistered', 'true');
          localStorage.setItem('setShowNotification', 'false');


          return { success: true, message: 'Your e-mail address has been verified.' };
        } else {

          await sendEmailVerification(user);
          return { success: false, message: 'Please check your email for confirmation.' };
        }
      } else {
        throw new Error('User not found');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error('Mail Confirmation Error: ' + error.message);
    }
  },
};

Component
onMounted(() => {
  store.dispatch('admin/fetchCategories');
  

  const registered = localStorage.getItem('isUserRegistered');
  if (registered === 'true') {
    store.commit('auth/SET_IS_USER_REGISTERED', true);

    store.commit('auth/setShowNotification', false);
  }
});

when email is already verified, the checkboxes are not changed in localstorage and notification is not lost.

Please, provide enough code to reproduce the problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . fetchCategories is not shown, and it's unknown when confirmEmail and the component are called. It's safe to assume that fetchCategories  is async and you should do await store.dispatch('admin/fetchCategories'). This looks like design problem, generally the logic listed in onMounted belongs to the store and shouldn't be scattered across the app. And there are persistence plugins for vuex to sync with LS in more coherent and bug-free way

You should probably move to Pinia + use VueUse for that kind of feature.
